# UrlHelper.Content with different domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have an ASP MVC Website which is hosted in a IIS server. This server have many subdomains pointing at.

My goal is to generate a full url with different domain when using UrlHelper.Content, without affecting the behaviours of UrlHelper.Action.

Example :

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home") ; // No change should be : /Home/Index
Url.Content("~/Content/image.png") ; // http://anothersubdomain.com/Content/image.png
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just place the domain in front of the output from `Url.Action`...

```
scr='http://sub.example.com@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'
```